# Use PM2 to start my Python app?

Tags: python, pm2

`python -m src.my_script` works great

`pm2 start src/my_script.py` starts the script but then fails.

`pm2 logs` shows relative path failures :

```
0|my_script | File "/usr/local/lib/src/my_script.py", line 9, in <module>
0|my_script |   from .util.fs import ensure_path
0|my_script | SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Line 9 referenced above is simply

```
from .util.fs import ensure_path
```

Is there something I need to do for PM2 to treat my python package the same way running python directly does?

*Update*: I was able to get this running by pointing PM2 to a shell script `pm2 start start_my_script.sh`, and then in that shell script running `python -m src.my_script`. Feels really hacky and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `--interpreter=python` as especified in [the docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#usage)

Comment: How does this work for a project of the form 'python -m mydir.main', which is what @AlienWebGuy asked initially?